# HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: windows, headers

We need to send get request with more than 16181 chars .
The most we can sent at this time is: 15,861
After that we get:

> HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

This is what configured in registry as a DWORD value:

```
MaxFieldLength: 65534 
MaxRequestBytes: 16777216 
UrlSegmentMaxLength: 32766
```

And in IIS:

```
maximum allowed content length 2147483647
maximum url length 2147483647
maximum url length 2147483647
```

web config:

```
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxUrl="2147483647" maxQueryString="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
```

...

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="largeTcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="false" transactionFlow="false" listenBacklog="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
        <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
      <reliableSession enabled="false" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="largeRestFullBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="largeRestFullBindingSecoundEndPoint" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="largeSoapBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mexHttpBinding" />
  </mexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

...

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="999999" maxUrlLength="999999" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="" validationKey="" />
  </system.web>
```

In HTTPERR I get:

```
2020-02-17 17:31:01 172.16.144.50 59371 172.16.144.50 80 HTTP/1.1 GET LONGURL- 400 - RequestLength -
```

The log cuts part of the url.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might also need to set it [in the registry](https://docs.secureauth.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14778828). I suggest not setting it to such exaggerated values such as `2147483647`. Did you verify the size of your cookies? Is this an AD domain? Which versions of Windows and IIS?

Comment: Hey @harrymc, sorry for not being clear, values already are set in registry. I have edit my question. The servers are not part of a domain, they are a workgroup. They are part of an auto scale group in aws, but I test on localhost, pointing to 127.0.0.1. 
 IIS version is 10.

Comment: Are you sending the request using GET or POST? GET is limited in length.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately via post. I know that is should be sent via post, but It can't be changed as the call is made by a third party. The thing is that in dev env we were able to get a response with the same url. I did not find any reason for that in registry, web config of IIS. Same values. You wrote about the size of cookies, I am not sure how to check it, but kerberos in not enabled - is it still relevant?

Comment: Unclear : GET or POST?

Comment: @harrymc GET...

Comment: GET is limited, but it also depends on the browser. By the error message, the message seems passed. I suggest heavy logging to find what's wrong with the client's headers, where my guess is cookies. For IIS, check also [MaxRequestLength](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_HttpRuntimeSection_MaxRequestLength). Note that this [old article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows) says MaxFieldLength limit is 65534.

Comment: Can you please give me more info about the cookie? Again get via postman in dev env works.

Comment: I can't know what is your cookie size, but it is part of the header. You will need to use IIS logging to find out what the difference is between the dev/prod requests.

Comment: It looks like there is no cookie set at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Debug is the solution, and logging is the tool.

Comment: @harrymc I get the error in HTTPERR log, so it gets  to IIS, but can't find if in IIS logs.  Not in event viewer. As I see it, it doesn't reach the application... how can I debug it? Where else can I look. BTW the is 100% no cookie.

Comment: @harrymc Hey man, I got it fixed. There were a mistake in registry, If you like me to accept your answer please post on, You can post your first comment. So you can get the bounty.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of `MaxFieldLength` and `MaxRequestBytes` also need to be set in the
registry under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
as DWORD values.

For more details with screenshots see the article
[HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)](https://docs.secureauth.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14778828).

Comment: Try something like this if the error your getting is a generic "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long." More than likely its actually a maxQueryString issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743176/1413798